# Any cross platform way to build cpp skeleton from a header?

Tags: c++

I'm tired of copy pasting the header into my cpp file then hacking at it until its in the correct form. Has anyone made a program to read a header file and make a corresponding cpp skeleton? I need something that is cross platform or bare minimum works on Linux. A vim plugin would also be acceptable.

Example

```
class A
{
    public:
        int DoSomething( int number );
}
```

Would produce the following file

```
int A::DoSomething( int number )
{
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2624

Comment: omg there is a vim plugin to do this i <3 you

Answer (score 2):

You can try to play around with [LazyCplusplus](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/). Or you can try out [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) for Visual Studio.

Instead of strinking C++ from the records, I'd rather wait for C++ promised **[modules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2073.pdf)**. :)

**Edit :** actually this seems a duplicate of your question : [Seeking code stub generator (from header files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020568/seeking-code-stub-generator-from-header-files)

Comment: English has to many words to describe the same thing /facepalm

Comment: +1 for lzz.  It's the business.

Comment: How I wish the modules came :x

Answer (score 0):

Almost every IDE has built-in features or plugins that do that for you - e.g. for Visual Studio [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) provides many convenience features.
There are also many code generation utilities, you could also create one use yourself using e.g. [gcc-xml](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) and the scripting language of your choice.