# Generate .cpp source from a .h file

Tags: c++, scripting, command-line, code-generation

The barebones version of a .cpp file is often not much more than a copy of the related header file with some braces instead of semicolons, `ClassName::` inserted in a few places, and removing the `virtual` keyword. Much of it could be generated with a one-line `sed` command, but it wouldn't be very robust for all the language features (templates come to mind).

Before I go write my own, are there any simple command-line utilities that will take a header file I provide and give me a skeletal .cpp file where I can fill in the blanks?

Comment: This is the domain of IDE add-ons.  Visual Assist for Visual Studio does this for example.  Shop around to see what fits yours.

Comment: My IDE is generally just vim ;) I can use Xcode too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seeking code stub generator (from header files)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020568/seeking-code-stub-generator-from-header-files)

Comment: I am sure you could find vim scripts doing that. I use emacs and I added very usefull scripts for C++.

Comment: Are vim tools from duplicate candidate really command line tools? Not everyone use vi, emacs or even ctags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most graphical editors have some plugins available to do that like vim, gedit or Eclipse.
But I am not aware of a shell or perl script to do that.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be a shell script; a plugin would be fine. Something for vim or Xcode would be preferable.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020568/seeking-code-stub-generator-from-header-files

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT has a feature of creating setters/getters provided you have defined variables in your .h. Also it provides "Implement method" - again it looks through your definitions in .h and implements methods giving them empty body. Maybe someone find this usefull.

And don't forget to read question, pointed by larsmans.