# Creating stub functionality in C++

Tags: c++

I have a piece of C++ code whose unit testing is to be done. e.g.

```
//totest.h
#include "lowerlayer.h"
class ToTest
{
    LowerLayer *ll;
public:
    ToTest();
    void function_totest();
};

//totest.cpp
#include "totest.h"
ToTest::ToTest()
{
    ll = new LowerLayer();
}
void ToTest::function_totest()
{
    ll->function_lowerlayer();
}

//lowerlayer.h
class LowerLayer
{
public:
    LowerLayer();
    void function_lowerlayer();
};

//lowerlayer.cpp
#include "lowerlayer.h"
LowerLayer::LowerLayer()
{
    //do nothing
}
void LowerLayer::function_lowerlayer()
{
    //do nothing
}
```

The four files viz. totest.h, totest.cpp, lowerlayer.h and lowerlayer.cpp are the production code files are are not supposed to be modified for unit testing.

I have a test app whose code is as follows

```
//testcode.cpp
#include "totest.h"
int main()
{
    ToTest *tt = new ToTest();
    tt->function_totest();
    //some asserts
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I have to create a stub functionality for class LowerLayer and its functions.
When function function_lowerlayer is called from function function_totest, both stub and real functions (one at a time) should be called using a controlling flag from testcode application.

Please provide some suggestions to design this requirement.
Thanks,
Ankur

Comment: What is stub "functionality"? A stub is a placeholder for a method that hasn't been completed, it generally contains comments as to how the method will be implemented and contains a dummy return value so the source file will compile.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - That isn't quite correct; stubs have specific meaning in a testing context.  [Here's a nice article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) explaining both `stubs` and `mocks` from a testing perspective.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Seeking code stub generator (from header files)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2020568/1309332).

Comment: @dbw This post is 10 months old...

Answer (score 1):

Try using GoogleMock in your tests.
http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/

> Inspired by jMock, EasyMock, and Hamcrest, and designed with C++'s
>   specifics in mind, Google C++ Mocking Framework (or Google Mock for
>   short) is a library for writing and using C++ mock classes. Google
>   Mock:
>
> lets you create mock classes trivially using simple macros, supports a
>   rich set of matchers and actions, handles unordered, partially
>   ordered, or completely ordered expectations, is extensible by users,
>   and works on Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, Windows Mobile, minGW, and
>   Symbian.

Comment: I tried using Mockpp framework and invested some time in that. But it didnot help me out. I am not sure of GoogleMock. Is there any other solution other than using a framework.

Comment: well, you could write your own mocks, but using a framework is so much easier.

Comment: For some reason, I thought Google Mock only worked on virtual or template classes. Is that not true?

Answer (score 0):

Try using cpp stub https://github.com/coolxv/cpp-stub

```
//for linux and windows
#include<iostream>
#include "stub.h"
using namespace std;
int foo(int a)
{   
    cout<<"I am foo"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
int foo_stub(int a)
{   
    cout<<"I am foo_stub"<<endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    Stub stub;
    stub.set(foo, foo_stub);
    foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```